# Error al usar la función Isnull : "The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)"

Tags: sql-server, funciones, casting

Estoy tratando de convertir a int 4 columnas para poder sumarlas y transformarlas en una sola columna.

Lo que intento de hacer esque sumar los nulos y remplazarlos por 0 para asi solamente dejar en la columna final el resultado obtenido de cada columna sumada.

El problema cuando quiero hacer esto me aparece `The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).`

Podria alguien ayudarme aver que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
select [User ID],
(cast(isnull([Q2_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS],0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q13_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS]),0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q57_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS]),0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q69_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS]),0) as int)) 
as Response
from [ExportResponses2015]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata sin usar <kbd>[</kbd> ni <kbd>]</kbd>, suprimelos quedando como lo siguiente:

```
select [User ID],
(cast(isnull(Q2_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS,0) as int) + 
cast(isnull(Q13_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS,0) as int) + 
cast(isnull(Q57_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS,0) as int) + 
cast(isnull(Q69_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS,0) as int)) 
as Response
from [ExportResponses2015]
```

Pero asegura que tengan valor :

```
Q2_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS
Q13_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS
Q57_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS
Q69_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes demasiados ")"; debería ser:

```
select [User ID],
(cast(isnull([Q2_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS],0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q13_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS],0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q57_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS],0) as int) + 
cast(isnull([Q69_ANALYTICAL SKILLS_ANALYTICAL SKILLS],0) as int)) 
as Response
from [ExportResponses2015]
```

Comment: @Elenasys: Gracias por tu ayuda!